# Infinite number of subsequential limits

Tags: real-analysis

Given that $a_n$ is bounded (but not necessarily convergent), is it possible to have an infinite number of distinct subsequential limits? Intuition says yes, but I cannot prove it.

Answer (score 2):

Take for example *the sequence* of all rational numbers in $\;[0,1]\;$ . This sequence has infinite (in fact, $\;2^{\aleph_0}\;$ , if you know what this is) different limit points.

Answer (score 0):

Pick a countably infinite number of limits, $c_i$.

Let $a_1, a_3, a_6, a_{10},..., a_{\frac{k(k+1)}2=\sum_{i=10}^k i}\rightarrow c_1$.

Let $a_2, a_4, a_7, a_{11},....,a_{\frac{k(k+1)}2+1=(\sum_{i=10}^k i)+1}\rightarrow c_2$

Let $a_5, a_8, a_{12},......,a_{\text{what the heck}} \rightarrow c_3$.

and so on.

The concept is obvious and the only issue is indexing.  But we can make each subsequence "thinner" and ...

Oh, here a much easier one (albeit not so efficient):

$a_2, a_4, .... a_{2^i} \rightarrow c_1$

$a_3, a_9, ..... a_{3^i} \rightarrow c_2$.

...

$a_{p_k}, a_{p_k^2}, .... a_{p_k^i} \rightarrow c_k$

while all the other terms can do whatever the heck they like.

Or simply take a sequence of arbitrarily but *normal*ly distributed real numbers.  Pick a term, then continue until you find a second that is closer to $c_1$ (as the sequence is normally distributed you will find one.  Eventually.)  Then continue until you find a third one that is even closer.  Do that an infinite number of times and then start all over to find terms that get close to $c_2$ and repeat the whole meshuggah an infinite number of infinite times.  (You didn't have anywhere pressing to get to, did you....)

Answer (score 0):

Think about $1,1,1/2,1,1/2,1/3,1,1/2,1/3,1/4,1,1/2,1/3,1/4,1/5, \dots.$